# Return AutoIncremeting ID upon insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that inserts into a table that has two values, `id` and `username`. The `id` field is autoincremeting so my stored procedure looks like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_test]
    @username varchar(50)
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.testtable(username)
        SELECT
            @username
        FROM 
            tbl.test2
        WHERE 
            username IS NOT NULL
```

How can I return the `id` even when there it is not explicitly stated? I attempted the `SCOPE_IDENTITY();` keyword but I was receiving blanks and nulls.

Comment: Your insert statement looks very strange. Why are you selecting the input variable but also including the table test2? If you want to insert just the parameter there is no need for the FROM in your insert. You also should consider not using the sp_ prefix (or even better no prefix at all). the sp_ prefix can cause performance and various other issues. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Answer (score 3):

Taking a guess as to what you want I think it would be something more like this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_test]
(
    @username varchar(50)
) AS 

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.testtable
    (
        username
    )
    VALUES
    (
        @username
    )

    select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're really inserting several rows from a table, you can get the ids this way:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.testtable(username)
output inserted.id
SELECT username
FROM dbo.test2
where username is not null
```